# How to Format Pivot Table Months in Mon-Yr format

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I would like to change the format of my dates to Mon-Yr.

My Graph

[image]

My Table has the format I want:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Right-click on the chart axis and select "Format Axis" from the pop-up menu

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the axis, select format axis and scroll to number. Enter the Format Code mmm-yy and click add. [image]

Comment: thank you for the reply. After I input 'mmm-yy' into the Format Code field, I selected 'Add'. After I clicked Add, the format code repopulated with '#,##0;-#,##0'. Also, my dates remained in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: What are your raw dates formatted as? "01/01/2017"?

Comment: raw dates in the sheet are displayed as 'mmm-yy' . However, it is a DATE() calculated field.

Comment: Is it a date calcated field soley to get the mmm-yy formatting? If so a better way to do it to use Field Settings (Right click on a date in your pivot)>Number Format>Custom>mmm-yy. You should then be able to link the axis to the source (see the bottom right of the image I posted) and it should give you the correct format without the need to change the format code. I'll have a play around and see how it can be done with calcauted field in case you need this anyway. Can you post the formula for you DATE calculated field?

Comment: thanks for the follow up will.

I used DATE(M2,L2,1)

M2= month column
L2 = year column

Answer (score 0):

I used DATE(M2,L2,1) M2= month column L2 = year column